# Dependencies of boto3

Tags: python, boto3, setup.py

I see that the requirements.txt(https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/requirements.txt) and setup.py (https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/setup.py). Also there is a file requirement-docs.txt.

Which are the exact dependencies for boto3 to run ?

I have a similar doubt for botocore as well as s3transfer

Comment: the answer is trickier. different APIs may need different liraries in runtime. Do you have some specific feature that is not working?

Comment: Which dependencies do they use while making rpms, I mean the spec files ?

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2022 the following packages are installed when you install boto3 into a blank venv in alphabetical order

boto3
botocore
dateutil
jmespath
s3transfer
six
urllib3